# Geocode.farm addresses are not allowed to be displayed? Alternatives?

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I just read the [ToS of Geocode.farm](https://geocode.farm/policies/terms-of-service/) and I am really curious about this paragraph :

> You may NOT display the information and data on either an internet or
>   intranet site, regardless of access restrictions to such site unless
>   reasonable precautions have been taken to hide and/or conceal the
>   source data(coordinate pairs and/or address(es) returned from the
>   Geocode.Farm API).

Do I understand this correctly - I can't use this service to e.g. convert GPS records to addresses that I show to the user?

This does not make any sense to me as this probably is one of the main use cases for reverse geocoding.

If this is true, does anybody know of an affordable and accurate alternative available for europe that allows storing and showing resulting addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for Geocode.Farm = Full Disclosure

Terms Of Service have been updated to remove this clause recently. It did cause confusion.

What it originally meant is don't display the results in plain text, parse it and then use the results.

For coders, I'll provide these examples:

```
Example, don't do:
$data=get_file_contents($url);
echo($data);
// or print_r($data);

Example, allowable usage:
$data=get_file_contents($url);
$json=json_decode($data,false);
echo($json->results->['0']->address);
```

That is all we were getting at when that term was written was not to give out the raw, unfiltered data. The reason was to reiterate the no reselling term.

Comment: Wow I really like the remake of your ToS, it converts your service from a complete deal-breaker to the perfect match for my needs. I also like the part about storing the data for later use. Thank you for updating us here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your thinking is correct but of course I only pretend to be a lawyer on TV.  How i read their TOS is you could give the results (ie show them to a user) in a paper copy as long as you don't profit from it (per part b of the same section you quoted) as that is not displaying the data on an internet/intranet. But if you put it on the internet/intranet you would have to scrub the data to make it anonymous.  And "reasonable precautions" and "hide" are fairly subjective terms, what they mean legally I really don't know.

Pretty restrictive terms imho :/

As for other services here is a very comprehensive list with what they can do, what they charge, etc

https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/OtherGeocoders/